# OpenLDAP only returns warning for expired password

Tags: java, spring, openldap, spring-ldap

I am trying to use OpenLDAP password policy for authentication.

I have set my ppolicy with the following:

> ```
> dn: cn=passwordDefault,ou=Policies,dc=company,dc=com
> objectClass: pwdPolicy
> objectClass: person
> objectClass: top
> cn: passwordDefault
> sn: passwordDefault
> pwdAttribute: userPassword
> pwdCheckQuality: 0
> pwdMinAge: 0
> pwdMaxAge: 7776000
> pwdMinLength: 8
> pwdInHistory: 5
> pwdMaxFailure: 5
> pwdFailureCountInterval: 600
> pwdLockout: TRUE
> pwdLockoutDuration: 0
> pwdAllowUserChange: TRUE
> pwdExpireWarning: 604800
> pwdGraceAuthNLimit: 0
> pwdMustChange: FALSE
> pwdSafeModify: FALSE
> ```

When testing the policy i can only get back a warning if the password was expired:

> ```
> try {
>         bindResult = bind(ldapConnection, userDN, userPassword);
>     } catch (LDAPException le) {
>         bindResult = new BindResult(le.toLDAPResult());
>     }
>    DraftBeheraLDAPPasswordPolicy10ResponseControl pwpResponse = DraftBeheraLDAPPasswordPolicy10ResponseControl.get(bindResult);
>  DraftBeheraLDAPPasswordPolicy10WarningType warningType = pwpResponse.getWarningType();
> ```

the only time that the warning type is not null is when the password is expiered.

when the account is locked after 5 failed attempts, ldap returns "bad credentials", but thats not true.

how do i get the correct reason that authentication failed?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

When you get the exception you can still also have response controls. I don't know what that looks like in Spring-LDAP but I've done it in JNDI via [`LdapContext.getResponseControls()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/naming/ldap/LdapContext.html#getResponseControls()). The response control should contain the lockout status.

However you need to be careful about this. You don't want to disclose to the user that the account is locked. It would be a *prima facie* security breach. You would be disclosing to the attacker that the account exists, and that further immediate attempts will not succeed, both of which aid him in his work.